# Weird directory created after executing mkdir after fork in Minix (USER=root)

Tags: c, terminal, minix

I'm busy coding a simple terminal in C on Minix 3.1. Simple commands such as `touch a.txt`or `date` is working perfectly. But when I make a directory such as `mkdir test` it creates a directory called `USER=root` and when I try create another one it says `USER=root: already exists`. I am logged in as the root. I am using execvp() in C to execute the terminal commands.

`ls` gives me this:

```
(null): HOME=/root: No such file or directory
(null): PAGER=more: No such file or directory
(null): LOGNAME=root: No such file or directory
(null): TERM=minix: No such file or directory
(null): PATH=/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/vin:/usr/bin: No such file or directory
(null): SHELL=/bin/sh: No such file or directory
(null): TZ=GMT0: No such file or directory
(null): EDITOR=vi: No such file or directory
USER=root:
```

Does anyone know what this actually means and how I can fix this. I have tried everything I could think of in my code to try fix this problem but nothing has worked.

Thanks for any help[image: First part of my code]

[image: Second part of my code]
[image: Last part of my code]

Im calling `executeCommand` from another function which just returns the status to loopShell

Comment: Show us your code. I have some idea what might be going on, but knowing is better than guessing.

Comment: Something is mixing up the environment list with the argument list.

Comment: @Anton.P He's not using bash and this has nothing to do with any .bashrc.

Comment: @duskwuff I have posted my code would you please take a look

Comment: Don't use screenshots to show your code. Use cut & paste instead.

Comment: I would love to but I cant copy and paste from Minix. You know how it is

Comment: No, I don't know how it is. If necessary copy the file somewhere where you can cut and paste it.

Comment: @RossRidge Im sorry about that. Its just that Minix doesn't allow for mounting of any kind so I can't share the file at all and I can't copy and paste outside of minix itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating the the argument list to `execvp` incorrectly. You're returning an array allocated on the stack (an array with automatic storage duration). Once the the function that created it returns the array is unallocated and the pointer to it is no longer valid. As simple quick fix would be to make the array `static` so that it remains allocated after the function returns. Eg:

```
static char *tokens[SPLIT_SIZE];
```

Another mistake in your program is trying to use `free` on objects not allocated with `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out. Again sorry for having to screenshot my code. I have just started using Minix and I haven't got any drivers enabled or anything. This worked thank you very much!